# laravel 5.1: get relation in with

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a model called user
with relation "travel" model
and travel model with relation "destination"

how can I get user in eloquent with travel and relation.

I know that I can get travel like this :

```
    $row = $this->model
        ->find($reqId)
        ->with('travel')
        ->first();
```

I want get destination of travels .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$row = $this->model->with('travel', 'travel.destination')->find($reqId)
```

Comment: ->with(['travel','travel.destinations'])